Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_header()
I'm receiving this error for my WordPress website via the Site Health error logs, and I'm unsure as to why.
DATE: 16-Jun-2024 22:11:19 UTC
MESSAGE TYPE: Fatal error
PROBLEM DESCRIPTION:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_header()
SCRIPT NAME: index.php
LINE: 8
The homepage for my website, via index.php, loads fine and as expected. The header is present as expected. Any idea why I'm receiving this particular error? The site I'm working on uses a custom theme that exists in the correct directory. Is this perhaps a false error?
I haven't taken any specific steps to resolve this, given that the homepage loads fine.

If you provide the code of index.php, I would be happy to look at it.

On another note, I see that the error message has a date of June 16. If you page loads fine and you don't have a more recent error log, I would say it's an outdated error.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
